# Using the fundamental theorem of calculus find $dy/dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> A function is given by: 
>  $$y(x) = \int_0^{x^2}t\sin(t)dt$$ Find
>   $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

This task really confused me, because - in the theorem - the integral is given in terms of $x$, not in terms of $x^2$. Therefore, I don't know how to proceed. One way to solve this I could think of is to change the integration bounds - to have only an $x$ up there, but I can' think of any way to do this. 
Would you mind giving me a hint on solving this? I have a hunch that it may have something to do with the chain rule, but still - I have never seen a problem like this.

Comment: We have
$$y(x) = \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t) dt = H(g(x))-H(f(x))$$
Where $H(x)$ is the antiderivative of $h(x)$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{d}{dx}\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} H(g(x))-H(f(x))$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} H(g(x))-H(f(x)) = g'(x)H'(g(x)) - f'(x)H'(f(x))$$
Since $H'(x) = h(x)$
$$g'(x)H'(g(x)) - f'(x)H'(f(x)) =g'(x)h(g(x)) - f'(x)h(f(x))$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) gives
$$
(F(x^2))'=2x \cdot F'(x^2)=2x \cdot f(x^2)
$$ where
$$
F'(t)=f(t).
$$ Can you see how to apply this?

Comment: Can we treat $y$ as a function of $x^2$ even though we have explicitly defined it as a function of $x$? ($x$ is in the parentheses). Would it not be more correct to look at this as $$y(f(x))$$ where $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_\text{y}^{x^\text{n}}\text{f}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right)=\text{n}\cdot x^{\text{n}-1}\cdot\text{f}\left(x^\text{n}\right)\tag1$$

Answer (score 1):

your integral is given by $$-x^2\cos(x^2)+\sin(x^2)$$ and the first derivative is $$2x^3\sin(x^2)$$